# roots of $x^2+2x \cot B+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sin A , \sin B , \cos A$ are in G.P. , then what can be said about the roots of

$x^2+2x \cot B+1=0$

i)real

ii)imaginary

iii)equal

iv)greater than 1

Answer (score 2):

By G.P. we have that $\sin^2 B =\cos A \sin A$. The discriminant of this quadratic equation is $$4\cot^2B-4=\frac{4(1-2\sin^2B)}{\sin^2B}=\frac{4(1-\sin 2A)}{\sin^2B} \geq 0.$$
Thus the roots will be real.

PS: we have to assume that $\sin B \neq 0$ (i.e. trivial GP is ruled out)